# xAuth Authentication for Twitter Share in Android?

Tags: java, android, twitter, xauth

I am working on the `Twitter Authentication`. The Basic Authentication will [expire](http://www.countdowntooauth.com/) on August 16th onwards. So we have to use `OAuth` to use Twitter Authentication. But Its some Complicated to implement. `XAuth` is cuts off the two steps. But the Problem is i [used](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) `Twitter4j` to authenticate.And also had bad documentation too. I want to use XAuth from 1.6 itself. Which package you suggest to use. and If any `example` or `tutorial` for specifiacally for Android to use `XAuth` Authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
In my code I did this:

```
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "your token");
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "your token secret");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(login, password);

AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
```

Then you must save your Token and Token secret from `AccesToken`

```
if (mAccessToken != null) {
    if (mAccessToken.getToken() != null && mAccessToken.getTokenSecret() != null) {
        saveAccessToken(mAccessToken.getToken(), mAccessToken.getTokenSecret());
    }
}
```

When you want to use your Token you just do this:

```
TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("[consumer key]", "[consumer secret]");
AccessToken accessToken = loadAccessToken();
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
```

Comment: These thinks are all i found in the twitter4j official site itself. Its getting the NullPointerException at the Second Time. And also in that site supports from Android 2.1.0. is that a problem?

Comment: Can you tell something about the Login and logout options using XAuth?

Comment: AFAIK you need only just to remove AccessToken - without this you won't be able to login :)

Comment: Usually xAuth needs to be especially enabled for an application to use it.