# Android Twitter xAuth example using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, xauth

Android: I am trying the following xAuth example for android share.

[xAuth Authentication for Twitter Share in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280328/xauth-authentication-for-twitter-share-in-android)

```
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "your token");
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "your token secret");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(login, password);

AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
//Then you must save your Token and Token secret from AccesToken

if (mAccessToken != null) {
    if (mAccessToken.getToken() != null && mAccessToken.getTokenSecret() != null) {
        saveAccessToken(mAccessToken.getToken(), mAccessToken.getTokenSecret());
    }
}
```

I am having IllegalStateException

`Exception Msg: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth consumer key/secret combination not supplied`

at the following line

```
AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
```

I made changes some thing like following

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance("login", "pass");
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(getString(R.string.twtAPIKey), getString(R.string.twtSecret));
            AccessToken mAccessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
```

and again I got exception 
`Exception Msg: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Basic authenticated instance.`

Any working example of xAuth ?

Comment: Are you sure your consumerKey and consumerSecret are correct? Also, I don't think this would give such an exception, but have they enabled XAuth for your application at Twitter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ' ve used following

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

     configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Consumer__Key);
     configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Consumer_Secret);
     Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();

     Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance("username","password"); 

     AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
     System.out.println("Access Token " +token );

     String name = token.getScreenName();
     System.out.println("Screen Name" +name);

     PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
     System.out.println(token);
```

And successfully login to Twitter using Android app using xauth

Comment: I tried above code it is giving following exception message

The screen name / password combination seems to be invalid.

Comment: @Faisal Khan Hi Have you got your keys enable for xAuth from Twitte. Probably this could be the reason for the error.

Comment: Yes we are have to request twitter guys to have special xauth account and keys.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.2.2 of twitter4j as a slight change. This works:

```
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.setOAuthConsumerKey("your_customer_key")
.setOAuthConsumerSecret("your_customer_secret")
.build();

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance(new BasicAuthorization(username, password)); // yes, use "BasicAuthorization" although that seems strange

AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
Log.d(TAG, "Access token: " + token.getToken());
Log.d(TAG, "Access token secret: " + token.getTokenSecret());
```

Remember that your twitter client application needs to be [authorized to use xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) before this works.