# how to use twitter api in android application for send tweet only

Tags: android

i want to know about twitter api for android application....
please send me link or source for twitter api which api just only for send the tweet....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="
                    + "https://www.google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

For more info, check my answer on this other post

[How to tweet from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741818/how-to-tweet-from-android-app/10358126#10358126)

Comment: @giancarlo its working fine. but how can i come back to the same activity after its posted on twitter?

Comment: Simple and useful. No twitter4j is needed for simple tweets.

Comment: @gian1200 Can you share the intent extras that i need to send .. i am passing intent.putExtra("text", ArticleListAdapter.shareContent);
   intent.putExtra("url", ArticleListAdapter.link); these values but the page not shows this message ??????

Comment: You dont need extras. Just a long url with parameters

Answer (score 3):

To share some text using standard android intents, only three lines of code are necessary. The user will be prompted to pick a method (and they can then choose Twitter.)

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's some text for Twitter.");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share this via"));
```

If you want to do more advanced stuff with Twitter:

I found that a lot of the solutions posted on the Internet were needlessly complicated. For me, it was only a couple additional lines of code beyond what Twitter4J tells you to do.

For my dollar, [Stephan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528471/695787) is the best.

I have some example code on github using his technique, [here](https://github.com/jamesonwilliams/AndroidTwitterExample).

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

          ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
          builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
          builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
          AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
          Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);
          try {
      twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(tweetText);
      return response.toString();
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return null;
       }
```