# How to tweet from Android app?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing an Android application and would like to have the functionality to send message on my twitter account (TWEET). Which APIs are available for this? Code samples will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to write a new Twitter client on your own? Or just have an app of you send tweets?

Answer (score 24):

If you just need to send a tweet, this can help you.

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="
                        + "https://www.google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

If you want to know which parameters are available, check this link
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/guides/parameter-reference1

Comment: +1, works nicely. On my Nexus 7 opens a "Complete action using..." dialog with Twitter and Chrome. For those who want to directly open the Twitter app if it's installed, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186753/56285).