# How to tweet both URL and Hashtags

Tags: android, twitter

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10358126/562776) on another thread, I am able to tweet **either** the URL:

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="
                        + "https://www.google.com";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

which shows up as:

> PUT TEXT HERE https://www.google.com

**or** the hashtags:

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="
                        + "https://www.google.com &hashtags=android,twitter";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

which shows up as:

> PUT TEXT HERE #android #twitter

But for some reason, I am unable to show **both** the URL and the hashtags in the twitter box.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question: There **shouldn't** be a space before `&hashtags`. In other words, the above should be written:

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=PUT TEXT HERE &url="
                        + "https://www.google.com&hashtags=android,twitter";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Hope this helps someone.