# When sharing on Android, why do hashtags work with the browser, but not the Twitter app itself?

Tags: android, twitter, hashtag

I am using a similar method for sharing on Twitter like:

[How to tweet both URL and Hashtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422568/how-to-tweet-both-url-and-hashtags)

This allows users without the twitter app to open a browser and share. However, I have noticed that hashtags are only passed into the message when being shared via browser. If the user chooses the official app, the hash tag disappears. Is this a known bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try so:

```
shareVia("twitter", "example.com"); 

....

private void shareVia(String packageName, String content) {    
    String toShare = content;

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, toShare);
    PackageManager pm = mActivity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        if ((app.activityInfo.packageName).contains(packageName)) {
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            mActivity.startActivity(shareIntent);

            break;
       }
    }
}
```