# Twitter on Android exception communication timeout

Tags: android, twitter

I want to make a program about Twitter on Android.

The code is like this:

```
public class ShareGenerator extends Activity {
    private final static String JTWITTER_OAUTH_KEY = "********";
    private final static String JTWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET ="***********"
Button menupopButton;
TextView txShare;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.share);
    this.txShare = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.lblshare);
    this.menupopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.menupop);
    menupopButton.setText("login");

    menupopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)

        {
            OAuthSignpostClient client = new OAuthSignpostClient(JTWITTER_OAUTH_KEY, JTWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET, "oob");
            URI url = client.authorizeUrl();
            client.setAuthorizationCode("pin");  
                        String[] accessToken = client.getAccessToken();
                        Twitter jtwit = new Twitter("cnitwoker", client);
            jtwit.setStatus("Messing about in Java");

        }
    });

}
```

The code is taken from an example, but there may be something wrong. What is "oob"? How can I get the pin?

I am getting the following error:

```
:03-22 17:24:21.087: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30260): winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: The operation timed out.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/winterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient.html, out-of-bounds, desktop based, that won't work in your android app.

I think you should be using xAuth, see this for and example: [Android Twitter xAuth example using twitter4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528458/android-twitter-xauth-example)

Comment: hi,Fredrik Leijon ,thank you for your answer,before do this,should i  emailed Twitter support to get them to turn on xAuth for my application? i just get JTWITTER_OAUTH_KEY  and  JTWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET

Comment: Reading on http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth it seems like you need to ask for it to be enabled for your application