# implementing twitter xauth in java

Tags: java, twitter, xauth

I am trying to implement twitter xauth using java.
I have already registered application and gained privilege for xauth. I already used API for login, post and other. Now I want to do it on my own. I have read the docs form twitter. I have understood some aspect of it. I want to implement it. Can anyone guide me for creating program.

I happen to read this thread [Implement OAuth in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964392/implement-oauth-in-java) but it didn't work for me.

And if I am not clear then ask me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example from the [Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA) source code:

[LoginActivity.loginXauth()](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/account/LoginActivity.java#L124), which then calls into [TwitterHelper.generateAccount()](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TwitterHelper.java#L326)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question on SO can help : [Android Twitter xAuth example using twitter4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528458/363573)

Have a look to [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/) too.

Comment: I don't want to use any api, I want to code it with java without any help of any api. I want to implement, not to use it.

Comment: sorry for late response, but I was trying to figure it out, how it is done. But I was unable, could you post a sample program(one file program), it would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, but I fear to don't understand you. You don't want to use an api but you can't figure out how Twitter4j do the job ... right ? Anyway, I can solely tell you to ask Twitter4j developers an help : http://twitter4j.org/en/development.html